# In Angular: How to Check the Previous route that is sending the Id, then apply the if else condition

Tags: angular, if-statement, routes, angular2-routing

So what I am trying to do is. I have three components in angular2+ Application

1 Home with (/home) route

2 Products with (/product) route

3 ViewProducts with (/view product) route.

HomeComponent has Feature products.

ProductComponent has only products.

They both have a method that routes them to viewProduct Component with their feature/product _id.

Now ViewCompnenet should check that from which component the _id is coming by checking the previous
route and then do some actions according to the route.

Here is my snippet.

```
   for example
   in FeatureProductComponent / ProductComponet both have this method
   
      SendProductId(_ProductId){
        this._MessengerService.SendFeatureProductId(_ProductId);//I am using rxjs to send data to viewComponent
        this._Router.navigate(['viewProduct']);
      }
 

     Now at ViewProduct Component.ts
     ngOnInit(): void {
       if(_Id is coming from /home (route or slug){

        //run some block of code here

       }else if(_id is coming from /product (route or slug)){

       
                     ///run some block of code here

          }
     }
```

Comment: That's not very stateless. A better approach could be to navigate with a queryParam (eg. "?from=home") and in the `ProductDetailsComponent` check the value of the queryParam (`this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.val`)

Comment: bro what params i can send to viewProduct to make condition on it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a StackBlitz with what you want:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xceqqt?embed=1&file=src/index.html

- In the `home.component.html` and the list.component.html, I've specified query parameters on the `a` elements, which will be appended on navigation to the show.component.

  ```
  <a ... [routerLink]='["/product", i]' [queryParams]="{from: 'home'}"><!-- or 'list' -->
      Go to product {{ i }}
  </a>
  ```
- In the `show.component.ts` I'm reading the value of the query parameter

  ```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.from = <string>params.from;
    });
  }
  ```
- Here you can put your `if` clause to decide what actions need to be taken.

Comment: Thanks bro I am pretty sure I Have found the solution in your answer.

Comment: Brother Do you have linkedin? I wana connect with you

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented and solved this using the logic given below. And it's working fine Just want to know is it a good way of solving this particular problem.

```
  viewProductComponent.ts
 
 Here docs are coming from the home/product component and it is an object
 {id:someId,Component:someComponent} and on this object i am checking form which
  component the data is coming.

     
 this._MessengerService.GetMessageWithData().subscribe((docs: any) => {
   
   if (docs.Component === "FeatureProductComponent") {
         console.log('Data Coming From Feature Product Component');
       } else if (docs.Component === "ProductComponent") {
         console.log('Data Coming From Feature Product Component');
       }
     });

  }
```